# Upgrading Python in Django cartridge in Openshift to install Quantlib-Python

Tags: python, django, openshift, openshift-client-tools, quantlib

I am using the Django cartridge in Openshift. This cartridge has Python version 3.3.2. Is there a way to upgrade the python to 3.6?

I am trying pip install QuantLib-Python in ssh console.
It gives me the following error:
Collecting QuantLib-Python
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement QuantLib-Python (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for QuantLib-Python.
I did the same install in my Windows machine which has a Python version 3.6.
Hence I feel that I will be able to my pip install if I upgrade the python.
I would appreciate any suggestion. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There will be no further updates to OpenShift Online V2. You should start looking at migrating to OpenShift Online V3. The latter has newer versions of Python, although no Python 3.6 as yet, latest is Python 3.5. Python 3.6 support in V3 is on its way though and will be coming at some point.